# Adding exteral parameters to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

This stored procedure executes ok :

```
insert into TEMP (name,surname) 
    select name, surname 
    from MEMBERS 
    where active = 1
```

However, I would like to add two more parameters (month, year) to the procedure.

I tried :

```
     @p1 date, 
     @p2 date 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEMP (name, surname, month, year) 
        SELECT 
            name, surname 
        FROM
            MEMBERS 
        WHERE
            active = 1, @p1, @p2
END
```

but it won't work. Why?

Parameters later I supply in my program like :

```
sp.Params.ParamByName('p1').asdateTime :=formatdatetime('mm', dxDateTimeWheelPicker1.DateTime);
sp.Params.ParamByName('p2').asdateTime :=formatdatetime('yyyy',dxDateTimeWheelPicker1.DateTime);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually :

```
@p1 date, 
@p2 date 
AS
BEGIN
insert into TEMP (name,surname,month,year) 
select name,surname,@p1,@p2 from MEMBERS where active=1
```

parameters are already set so ...

Comment: can u explain how it is correct ...@user3351050
and how you accepted this answer

Comment: @ Chanukya what is wrong with the answer ? This is a stored procedure with parameters we are talking about. How can it be wrong? :) When procedure executes it will look for the parameters. They don't need to be in the same table.

Comment: Think practically any one will put month as name of column for datatype date and same for year and that to you are writing with out having any 
coding standards and giving negative vote for my question ...@user763539

Answer (score -1):

while creating table temp add columns (month,year) that should be int datatype for both columns

since we cannot insert @p1,@p2 directly in insert statement
and @p1 and @p2 datatype is date time from which variable we need to take that he user didn't mention 
so i assumed like month from one variable and year is from another variable

```
declare  @p1 date, 
     @p2 date 

    AS
BEGIN

insert into TEMP (name,surname,month,year) 
select name,surname,month(@p1),year(@p2) from MEMBERS where active=1

END
```